# jQuery KeyUp() Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

Once the user preses "a", the button colour will change, then once the user releases the "a" button it *should* change again. The button only changes colour once the letter "a" has been pressed, not when released.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>website</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(document).keyup(function(event) {
        if ( event.which == 97){
            $('.button0 input').css('color', 'rgb(0, 0, 255)');
        }
    });
    $(document).keypress(function(event) {
        if ( event.which == 97){
            $('.button0 input').css('color', 'rgb(128, 0, 0)');
        }
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.button0 input{
    position:fixed;
    left:41px;
    top:12px;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:8px;
    font-weight:normal;
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="button0">
        <input type="button" style="width: 303px;height: 165px;" value="Button"/>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using `keypress` and `keyup` rather than `keydown` and `keyup`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [jQuery API page](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) for `.keypress()`:

> Note that keydown and keyup provide a code indicating which key is pressed, while keypress indicates which character was entered. For example, a lowercase "a" will be reported as 65 by keydown and keyup, but as 97 by keypress. An uppercase "A" is reported as 65 by all events. Because of this distinction, when catching special keystrokes such as arrow keys, .keydown() or .keyup() is a better choice.

So you need to change `event.which == 97` to `event.which == 65` in your `keyup` handler.

Comment: Because there's only one key with the character `A` on your keyboard, but there's lowercase and uppercase versions of the character `A`. The code for the key and uppercase character is the same here, you can use an [ASCII chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) to find out the right code to use.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to check for keyCode when you do keyup again.. If I understood correctly then the below code should work..

```
$(document).keyup(function(event) {
     $('.button0 input').css('color', 'rgb(0, 0, 255)');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/AU6te/) here

If you really want to compare the key and change color, then you can do something like below,

Updated [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/AU6te/2/) here

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    if ( event.which == 65){
        $('.button0 input').css('color', 'rgb(128, 0, 0)');
    }
}).keyup(function(event) {   
   if ( event.which == 65){
        $('.button0 input').css('color', 'rgb(0, 0, 255)');
   }
});
```

Link to [event.which](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/eventwhich-code-list-just-for-help) code list.

Comment: +1 for matching `keydown` to `keyup`. Regarding the test of keycode on `keyup`, my guess is it probably doesn't matter for this specific problem, but in general the user can press and hold multiple keys so it is neater to test specifically for the "a" key.

Answer (score 0):

It seems event.which means something slightly differently in the two functions, because this will work (chrome):

```
$(function() {
    $(document).keyup(function(event) {
        if ( event.which == 65){
            $('.button0 input').css('color', 'rgb(0, 0, 255)');
        }
    });
    $(document).keypress(function(event) {
        if ( event.which == 97){
            $('.button0 input').css('color', 'rgb(128, 0, 0)');
        }
    });
});
```

Perhaps jQuery is normalizing event.which (per http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) for `keyup` but not `keypress`.

Comment: is there a certain way to convert the 97 to 65?

Comment: That's not a jQuery thing, that's the way the browser handles the events. `keypress` gives you the character associated with the keypress, while `keyup` gives a keycode.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you are listening to the wrong key on your [`keyUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) function, see the documents for [`keypress()`](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/):

> Note that keydown and keyup provide a code indicating which key is
>   pressed, while keypress indicates which character was entered. For
>   example, a lowercase "a" will be reported as 65 by keydown and keyup,
>   but as 97 by keypress. An uppercase "A" is reported as 65 by all
>   events. Because of this distinction, when catching special keystrokes
>   such as arrow keys, .keydown() or .keyup() is a better choice.

So to fix your code, change the keyup event to:

```
$(document).keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 65) {
        $('.button0 input').css('color', 'rgb(0, 0, 255)');
    }
});
```

[**See it working here**](http://jsfiddle.net/EDspN/)